# /etc/environment and /etc/profile.d/* ignored for the root user

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

How do I set global environment variables in Ubuntu, in such a way, that they would apply also to `root` user?

Setting `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/environment`
**or** in `/etc/profile.d/my_settings.sh`
**both works for usual user**, but not for `root`.

I'm logging in as root using `sudo bash` or `sudo zsh`.

*NOTE: using Ubuntu 10.04.*

Answer (score 12):

You will need to get into a real root login shell:

```
sudo su -
```

Comment: I get an error: "Sorry, user [...] is not allowed to execute '/bin/su' as root on [...]"

Comment: Have you used `sudo` before `su`?

Comment: `sudo -i` also works.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky `sudo su` without the hyphen (not an en-dash or em-dash; that *could* break things) does not execute /etc/profile, which does not answer OP's question